# QGIS 3.4.14-1 start menu is empty

Tags: qgis, installation, windows-7

I am using Win7.  I had QGIS 3.4.12.1 standalone installed with `QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.12-1-Setup-x86_64.exe`.

I downloaded new LTR standalone version `QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.4.14-1-Setup-x86_64.exe`.
This setup asks for uninstalling my previous one.
I acepted, and anfter removing previous version, new one **is not present in start menu**.  I can find **QGIS 3.4 entry**, but **is empty**.

I uninstalled both versions and cleaned registry form older QGIS versions but **new installation have the same problem**.

How should I install 3.4.14-1 version in Windows 7?

---

*Clarifications:*

Installation is ready. No error messages. Only start menu is empty.

Qgis runs when I rename qgis-ltr.bat.tmpl to qgis-ltr.bat.

But it seems to be that something is wrong with start menu. Qgis 3.4 menu is created empty and no icons in desktop. QGIS 3.4 is present in Start menu and as a directory in desktop. But both are empty.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments, because they were written believing it was an OSGeo4W installation. Which was clarified in the following chat conversation: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102642/discussion-between-gabriel-de-luca-and-jlopez. In turn, the post was edited to explain that it is a standalone install. About which I do not know why the behavior to which the question refers is due.

Comment: De Luca made comments that I answered with this messages:

* Installation is ready. No error messages. Only start menu is empty. Qgis runs when I rename qgis-ltr.bat.tmpl to qgis-ltr.bat But it seems to be that something is wrong with start menu. 
* Qgis 3.4 menu is created empty and no icons in desktop.
* QGIS 3.4 is present in Start menu and as a directory in desktop. But both are empty.